# Getting rid of fireflies on render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

This question has been asked a few times before, but even after following tutorials such as [this one](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/)

and following the settings, I've been unable to get rid of fireflies in my render. The current render looks like this: [image]

What additional steps can I take to decrease the amount of fireflies / reduce graininess in my renders? I've tried clamping and all of the other techniques in the tutorial but it doesn't seem to help, or at best, has a minimal effect.

Here's the model itself. It's pretty simple, no textures (just shaders).
[image]

For reference, the blend file is here: https://transfer.sh/yITqe/spaceship.blend

Comment: I don't see any fireflies on the render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the samples amount helps enormously in your scene.
Also, you are mixing up the terms a bit. Fireflies are those white pixels that wont go away even when rendering with a lot of samples.
What you are experiencing is just called noise.

Result with 1000 samples:
[image]

Comment: I guess I wasn't giving it enough time - when looking at the top left of the viewport now, I see how many samples it has gone through

Comment: On a side note: unshaded test renders are often noisy since the plain white clay shaders reflect a lot of light, and don't hide noise well. The darker your surface, the less energy you end up with in noisy indirect light. And noise is harder to spot on textured surfaces since the surface itself is "noisier" in a way